# 401 unauthorized response when doing user registration in Django rest framework using serializers and Api view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

A bit of an update. Here is my serializers.py code:

```
class SellerRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Seller
        fields=['email','password','first_name','last_name','company_name','seller_desc','seller_image','seller_verification']
        extra_kwargs={
            'password':{'write_only':True}
        }
    #def create should be done since this is a custom User model
    def create(self,validate_data):
        return Seller.objects.create_user(**validate_data)
```

and In my views.py I have this code:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }


class SellerRegistrationView(APIView):  #
    def post(self,request,format=None):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        serializer=SellerRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data) 
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            seller=serializer.save()
            token=get_tokens_for_user(seller)

            
            return JsonResponse(serilizer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class SellerLoginView(APIView):
    def post(self,request,format=None)
permission_classes = [AllowAny]:
        
        serializer=SellerLoginSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            email=serializer.data.get('email')
            password=serializer.data.get('password')
            seller=authenticate_seller.authenticate(request,email=email,password=password)  #where i use custom authenticator that uses email of the user and not username

            if seller is not None:
                token=get_tokens_for_user(seller)
               
                return JsonResponse({'token':str(token)},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'errors':{'non_field_errors':['Email or password is not valid']}}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND) #when serializer sends an error, it can send non_field_errors as one of the error response but in frontend we catch that error as errors to get all the errors. so to also obtain the non_field_error, we send it inside errors as an object that we will probably jsonify

        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

now with this url:`path('sregister/',SellerRegistrationView.as_view(),name='sregister'),`

when i make the request using thunder client i get this as a response:

{ "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." } with a 401 status . I don't know why this is happenning. i have tried using       `permission_classes=[AllowAny]` in my views but same response.

The issue went away when i removed

```
DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        
    ]
```

from settings.py. But don't i need that in the future.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'seller.authenticator.SellerAuthenticator', #our custom seller authenticator class that uses email for authenticaation and not username
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', #the inbuilt default user authenticator
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

where is it wrong?

code for SellerAuthenticator on authenticator.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import Seller

class SellerAuthenticator(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            seller = Seller.objects.get(email=email)
        except Seller.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if seller.check_password(password):
                return seller
        return None
```

The issue seems to be caused by rest framework permissions and i don't know how to combat that. I will need authentication for logging in later on and adding products in the ecom site.

On the headers of Thunder Client I have this. How do I deal with www-authenticate.

```
ResponseHeaders
Header             Value
date    :           Tue, 22 Aug 2023 13:41:53 GMT
server   :          WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.3
content-type:       application/json
www-authenticate:   Token
vary             :  Accept, origin, Cookie
allow            : POST, OPTIONS
x-frame-options  : DENY
content-length   : 58
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy   :  same-origin
cross-origin-opener-policy:   same-origin
```

Comment: Can you add the code of 'seller.authenticator.SellerAuthenticator' I think the problem might be there

Comment: i added it. it doesnot seem to use rest permissions unless something else is causing errors